# policy gradient loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, policy-gradients

I am confused with the process for calculating loss. My code is below:

```
logits = policy.predictions(states) 
negative_likelihoods = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=**actions**, logits=logits)

weighted_negative_likelihoods = tf.multiply(negative_likelihoods, q_values)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(weighted_negative_likelihoods)

gradients = loss.gradients(loss, variables)
```

logits is the output of policy network without softmax.

My question is :

What does **actions** mean ? Is it the action that agent has executed at t step or it should execute at t step ?
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to reopen this question? It is totally clear to me what the OP is asking.